# eclipse mistakenly interprets packages as "resources", or source folders

Tags: java, eclipse, tree, package

I'm importing an existing source tree as an Eclipse Java project. When I do, I get errors in classes (such as mycompany.logging.LogEntry) along the following lines:

```
The package mycompany.logging does not match the expected package ""
```

The problem seems to be that Eclipse does not realize that the directory src/mycompany/logging is a package directory --- instead it thinks it's a source folder in its own right, analogous to src/, and that LogEntry is part of the default package in that folder.

Can anyone advise? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have, in your imported project, configured the source path to be src?

[image: Java Build Path]

Then you should see packages like:

```
mycompany.logging
```

See also [Configuring an Eclipse Java Project](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=367962)

Comment: Thanks! In the "new project" wizard, I hit the "next" button and removed redundant source folders (e.g., "src/mycompany/logging"), leaving only "src". This fixed it. Thanks again.

Comment: @George You are welcome. I am glad this settings worked for you.