# Android, Eclipse, and SVN - How does source folder naming affect transmission?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, svn

Hey. Been running into a rash of problems trying to make projects version controlled. Here is a picture of my eclipse set up on my main dev pc. Everything works fine here.

[image]

I decide to check out a copy onto my laptop and here is what I get:

[image]

There are errors everywhere because apparently 'something' isn't looking for class files until it reaches the end of a 'dot path', or something like that.

What exactly is going on with this dot hell?

Comment: Are you using a different Eclipse view (other than package explorer) in your second screenshot? What perspective are you in? Did you clean the project after importing it? And are you using the same 1.6 JDK (or 1.5) on both machines? I'm sorry if my questions sound very simple, but you're not giving us a lot to go on. Some more accurate error logs, or some bigger screenshots, would help. It's probably just a difference between your development environment on your laptop vs the one on your desktop.

Comment: I checked the dev environments, and both are 1.6 JDK. Your intuition about the different views was correct; one was in Java, the other in Java EE. However the problem remains as such: if package src/com.touch has any classes in it and you have package src/com.touch.touchbox, it will ignore com.touch as a source package. Simple solution is to be more careful about how I name source. Thanks for your insight however.

Comment: The Java EE version of Eclipse is not officially being supported by the Android plugin. I'm just saying this, because you might have other problems because of this. Usually, it's even a good idea to keep different Eclipse environments for different development environments, and mix in as few plugins as possible. In theory, eclipse is supposed to support multiple environments through its plugin system, but in reality that doesn't work very well, and it's best to maintain several different eclipses instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Right click on the folder that
>   contains the root of your package and
>   select the Build Path->Use as source
>   folder.

See this: [eclipse mistakenly interprets packages as "resources", or source folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180469/eclipse-mistakenly-interprets-packages-as-resources-or-source-folders/1180536#1180536)